# How can I search for text in a specific part of a webpage in Selenium (Python) ? With pictures:

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, search, text

So I've been trying to search for specific keywords on a webpage using selenium in python, but can't seem to figure out how to search for specific text in a specific area. As shown in the picture, when I search the word "Sim" in chrome, several spots are highlighted. The red region is the only place I am looking for code in. I've using the xpaths to identify the text, as nothing else is available for them.

This is the code so far:

```
else:
    print("Nothing here yet 1")
    if driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Sim')]"):
        login_to_reply = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='app']/main/div[@id='content']/div/div/div/div/div/div/article/header[1]")
        login_to_reply.click()                         
        time.sleep(5)
```

if anyone could help and let me know what I'm not understanding, I would really appreciate that, thank you.

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: What makes your red circled area different to the rest of the comments/posts on the page? - is it by a specific author? Is it not replied to yet? Is it that you want to check the the [first post on the page only]?  Do you want [the first post anywhre on the page where "sim" is metnioned] the page?  Or any other? - these are possible with xpaths, you just need to clarify what you need :-)

Comment: @DebanjanB I've added some more detail and another example of a similar page, https://community.giffgaff.com/d/33231984-referred-a-friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the additional information in the comments, to search for keywords in the FIRST POST on the page you can use the following xpath:

```
(//article)[1]//div[@class='Post-body'][contains(normalize-space(),'point')]
```

The key bit is: `(//article)[1]`  - it's locking the further identifiers to within the first `[1]` located `article` tag. The rest just reduces repetition within the dom and finds your text whoever the nested tags are strucutred.

Based on [the link provided](https://community.giffgaff.com/d/33231984-referred-a-friend), that matches the top post only. You can see searching for keyword "point" only gets 1 hit even though it's in multiple posts...
[image: xpath for points]

The text 'point' can be swapped out for 'sim' or whatever you want to filter.

---

Looking at you code, i have some more suggestions:

1/
Your second xpath for "login to reply" is not great. Long copied xpaths like that are typically flakey and troublesome. You can use the same technique as above to click the reply within that article box:

```
(//article)[1]//button[span[text()='Reply']]
```

2/

You also need to be aware that this line won't work as you expect.

```
 if driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Sim')]"):
```

If the element is not found, it does not return false - it returns a NoSuchElement exception and fails (and stops) the script.

You need this to be a [try/except block](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)

It would need to look like this:

```
try:
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//article)[1]//div[@class='Post-body'][contains(normalize-space(),'point')]"):
    login_to_reply = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//article)[1]//button[span[text()='Reply']]")
    login_to_reply.click()
    time.sleep(5)
except:
    print("Text was not found")
```

I've not run this but if it doesn't work let me know and i'll look again.

Comment: Yes! You're "try:
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//article)[1]//div[@class='Post-body'][contains(normalize-space(),'point')]"):
    login_to_reply = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//article)[1]//button[span[text()='Reply']]")
    login_to_reply.click()
    time.sleep(5)
except:
    print("Text was not found")" code worked like a charm, thanks! On a sidenote, considering I'm only searching for a single keyword, what changes would I have to make to this code to search for two keywords together, e.g. search for "sim" and "broken", and then a response from there?

Comment: To add more keywords, keep adding more square brackets at the end. For example for 2 key words in any order : driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//article)[1]//div[@class='Post-body'][contains(normalize-space(),'sim')][contains(normalize-space(),'broken')]")

Comment: thank you, I very much appreciate the help. Does the keyword in the bracket include both upper and lowercases for the answers? E.g. if someone wrote "sIm" in their answer due to incorrect grammar on their behalf, would the code still pick up on that given that the keyword is "(normalize-space(),'sim')"?

Comment: on a sidenote, I seem to get this error "raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: {Alert text :
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }" sometimes when I run my code. What does this mean exactly?

Comment: An alert means there's an alert on the page. You need to switch to it, and clear it. You say occasioanlly, but you might find it's happening for specific pages you visit or at specifc times.  If you're not sure what an alert is put this in your address bar in chrome `javascript:(alert("I am an alert"))` or look at this site: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp